# How to retrieve/decode timestamp from firebase database key?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I didn't save timestamp in a some values and i need to find out timestamp from firebase database generated key. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

After googling for some time and not finding the answer I decided to have a look at firebase's source code.

Once I found how keys are generated (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/database/src/core/util/NextPushId.ts)

I found out that timestamp is converted to a 8-symbol string at the beginning of a key + some random symbols are added after that.

So i've written a small script to decode timestamp.

```
const decodeFirebaseKey = key => {
  // chars firebase use for generating keys
  const CHARS = '-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  let timestamp = 0
  
  // we only need to decode first 8 symbols
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    const index = CHARS.indexOf(key[i])
    timestamp = timestamp * 64 + index
  }
  
  return timestamp
}
```

Hope it will save you some time.

I've also uploaded script to a gist: https://gist.github.com/Stas-Buzunko/b4f2ed1dc122cdb1867e13a731fc5dcf